# NodeJs from JSON to rows

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I want to modify my JSON data from:

```
[
 {
  "a":1
  "b":["a","b"]
 }
...
]
```

to

```
"a" "b"
 1   a
 1   b
```

How can i achieve this in Node JS?
I've tried with .map() but i can't understand how to use it well.
The result should be used to insert into a SQL table.

Comment: just loop and reorganize your array with simple for loop

Comment: I can't figure it out i know one loop should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two loop but you can refactor it ,

```
let array = [
 {
  "a":1,
  "b":["a","b"]
 }
]

 let finalArray = [];
 for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
   for(let j = 0 ; j< array[i].b.length ; j++)
    finalArray.push({a:array[i].a , b:array[i].b[j]})
 }
```